# How to Add a custom button on the top of keyboard in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I do not know why but there is no android example regarding adding a custom button/panel above the keyboard as can be done in iOS.

I would like to add a button above the keyboard as follow

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22438/trying-to-make-next-and-prev-buttons-on-keyboard-through-custom-renderer-any-suggestions

but this is for ios. I searched a lot for android and no single example I found. I saw that you can add a panel and move it up while keyboard appearing but this is not what I am looking for. Because this will bring many troubles considering different screen sizes and landscape mode.

I just want simply added a layout panel just above the keyboard (I'll add an image button on the layout)

Answer (score 0):

What have you used as parent layout?

ScrollView?

Try using a `RelativeLayout` with the property called `android:alignParentBottom="true"`. 
It will keep any view to the bottom of the screen. It may help you.

It only works in the Xamarin.Android only. For Xamarin.Forms you need to use

```
<RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="End"></RelativeLayout>
```

Check this out for help : [Stick Layout to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709788/stick-layout-in-xamarin-forms-to-bottom)

Comment: thank you for the answer but its not exactly what I want to do. My app is complicated a bit. There are some special editboxes which should show that kind of keyboard. I just need to customise keyboard and add a layout on .. I tried RelativeLayout but it did not work to me. It shows until my editbox, but under of it there is a panel which laid behind the keyboard

Comment: @ertan2002, Check this out :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry#customizing-the-return-key

For Android, you do not need to show the button. Keyboard default bottom will do it.

Comment: thank you but I think you did not undersand me. I want a custom button that when I click this I will show camera view to scan QR code. That means, user can write text or if they want they can open the camera to scan instead of typing. But It should be an external button. for example, I want to keep "Done" button on the keyboard and as well as have a seperate button with an icon (QR code icon) on the keyboard. Is it possible?