# Dynamic Add Entry of Player in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an int of the numbers of players and of this number I need to generate the numbers of entries for the player's name. I created 24 entries and made them visible and not visible but I think this is not "clever".

I tested a little bit like:

```
var layout = new Stacklayout();
var playerentry = new Entry {Text = "Test"};
layout.children.Add(playerentry);
```

combining this with a for loop with i = number of players it doesn't work.

Maybe someone can help this easy question.
UPDATE:

This is the complete code:

Comment: could you add all code?

Comment: "doesnt work" - what do you mean?  Doing this in a loop should work.  Can you post the actual code that you tried?

Comment: As @Jason, suggested using for loop should work, but I guess you want to update the player field in the DB or somewhere else according to the user input., for this I would suggest using a ListView with List<Players> as ItemsSource and bind Text of Entry to the Name property of the Player object. I'll try to add an answer to this.

Comment: @FelixGebert As Nikhileshwar's code, there is ObservableCollection, you can add number items according to user input value, if you want to loop entry, you can loop this ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ListView or BindableLayouts where number of items or views or unknown.

**Xaml**:

```
    <ListView x:Name="playerList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="Enter player name"/>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**Code behind**

```
var playerCollection = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    playerCollection.Add(new Player());
}
playerList.ItemsSource=playerCollection;
```

**Player class**

```
public class Player : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name = "Unknown";

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Hope this helps!! Comment for any queries.

Comment: ObservableCollection could not be found.
And is new Player(), not dynamically?

Comment: The Number of Entries is an input by user as an int and this number for example 8 should generate 8 entries of players.
for my newbie talent i hoped i can do a for loop 8 times and put in the code i posted and then the entries are generated 8 times and added 8 times to my stacklayout.

Comment: then use a loop to create 8 Player objects.   `ObservableCollection` is in `System.Collections.ObjectModel`

Comment: I have added the addition of item to collection in a for loop as you had asked. Please do check.

Comment: @Nikhileshwar: Thanks a lot for the answer. works fine. all my names of players are safed in playercollection now, or? can i handle this collection like a list? and for the xaml file: i have an button on the bottom of my page and i want to have it fixed on the bottom of my page and over there should be my entries. can you please help me again?

Comment: 1. can i handle this collection like a list? ==> Sorry, I don't get your requirement properly.  2. i want to have it fixed on the bottom of my page ==> Are you looking for this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709788/stick-layout-in-xamarin-forms-to-bottom)